# Box Overflow Clipping Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using three js is there any way to clip or hide object out of its parent? For example i have a box and a sphere inside of this box like on image: [sphere inside box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojHIj.png)

I want to clip or hide the part of sphere that is outside of the box. To put it simply, i need similar logic like css overflow:hidden works;

I am very new working with three.js, don't judge me if i'm asking something dumb. Anyways,my code is here:

```
// Simple example
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true, antialias:true});
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  console.log(renderer)
    // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);

    // controls
  controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    const materialA =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        roughness: 0,
        metalness: 0,
        color: 0xffffff,
    })
  const materialB = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        roughness: 0,
        transmission: 1,
        thickness: 0.5
    });
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(-5,30,30),materialA);
  sphere.position.set(5, 0, 0)
  
  const box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(12,12,12),materialB);
   scene.add(box);
  
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 1);
  light.position.set(10, 10, 0);
  const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 1);
  light2.position.set(-10, -10, -10);
  scene.add(sphere, box,light,light2);
}

function animate() {    
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to using clipping as you suggest.

You have some example here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip

First you have to enable local clipping on the renderer
(see [WebGLRenderer.localClippingEnabled](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=renderer#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.localClippingEnabled)). Then you can add some clipping planes to specify the area you want to clip. For this, you can use the [Math class](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=plane#api/en/math/Plane).

So in your example, you have to:

Enable local clipping:

```
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
```

Create a plane:

```
const clipPlane1 = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), 0);
clipPlane1.translate(new THREE.Vector3(6, 0, 0));
```

And finally, specify the plane in the material:

```
clippingPlanes: [clipPlane1],
clipIntersection: true
```

---

Here is your entire code:

```
// Simple example
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

let renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    console.log(renderer);
    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);

    // planes
    const clipPlane1 = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), 0);
    clipPlane1.translate(new THREE.Vector3(6, 0, 0));

    // controls
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    const materialA = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        roughness: 0,
        metalness: 0,
        color: 0xffffff,
        clippingPlanes: [clipPlane1],
        clipIntersection: true,
    });
    const materialB = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        roughness: 0,
        transmission: 1,
        thickness: 0.5,
    });
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(-5, 30, 30), materialA);
    sphere.position.set(5, 0, 0);

    const box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(12, 12, 12), materialB);
    scene.add(box);

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 1);
    light.position.set(10, 10, 0);
    const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 1);
    light2.position.set(-10, -10, -10);
    scene.add(sphere, box, light, light2);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```